# Hot to track progress with RxAndroid?

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-android

I have in my project Retrofit library and RxAndroid.

For example I've called some method from my api

```
public void loadSomething() {
   getApi().getSomething()                
      .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(new Subscriber<Something>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {

                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(Something s) {

                    }
                });
}
```

How should I track progress of this observable for example to prevent user to start it second time? 
Should add my custom flags something like before start set `inProgress = true;` and in all callback methods set `inProgress = false;`?

Can I do it with RxAndroid functionality? Or is it guarantee that one call to api will not be started few times in parallel?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Do operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/do.html).

You can set the `inPogress = true` in `doOnSubscribe()` and `inProgress = false` in `doOnComplete()`.

Also calling `subscribe` returns a [Subscription](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Subscription.html). You can use it to check if the call has finished using `isUnsubscribed()`.

Comment: I would use doOnTerminate to always reset the inProgress value, even when an error happened.